# Number theory problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $P(x) \in Z/pZ[x]$ be a polynomial of degree d. Prove that P(x) has d distinct roots in
Z/pZ if and only P(x) divides $x^p-x$, namely,

$x^p-x \equiv P(x)Q(x) \bmod p$
for some polynomial Q.

Suggestions on where to start/how to tackle such a problem?

Comment: Look at examples. Try $p=3$ and factor the polynomial $x^3-x$ as completely as you can. Do the same for $p=5$ and $x^5-x$. You should see what’s going on soon enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints:

- Prove that $x^p-x$ has $p$ distinct roots in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, so every element mod $p$ is a root with multiplicity $1$.
- Use the root theorem (the element $a$ is a root of $q(x)$ if and only if $x-a$ divides $q(x)$) to find a factorization of $x^p-x$. Show/verify that every divisor of $x^p-x$ has distinct roots.
- If $P(x)$ has $d$ distinct roots, use the root theorem to write a factorization of $P(x)$ and verify that it divides $x^p-x$.